# how to display data from sqlite in UITableView in Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, uitableview, storyboard

I create one application.
in my application I store 2 array in sqlite table DataBase but I can't display from sqlite in UItableView.
I searching in google but not found about display data in storyboard from sqlite.!!!
please guide me that how to display data from sqlite DB in tableview.
this is my code :

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#define DataName @"DB.sqlite"

@implementation ViewController
{
    NSDictionary * dictionary;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *Name = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Ribery",@"Ronaldo",@"Messi",@"Zannati",@"Totti", nil];
    NSArray *Team = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"byern",@"R.Madrid",@"Barcelona",@"Inter",@"Rome", nil];
    for (int i = 0; i < [Name count]; i++)
    {
        NSString * name = [Name objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString * team = [Team objectAtIndex:i];
        dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:name,@"Name",team,@"Team",nil];
        NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into tableFootball (Name,Team) values('%@','%@')",[dictionary objectForKey:@"Name"],[dictionary objectForKey:@"Team"]];
        [self executeQuery:query];
    }

}
-(NSString *) dataFilePath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"PATH %@",[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:DataName]);
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:DataName];
}
-(void)executeQuery:(NSString *)query
{
    //NSLog(@"QUERY : %@",query);

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if(sqlite3_open([[self dataFilePath] UTF8String], &DataBase) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(DataBase, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"query Statement Not Compiled");
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(DataBase);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Data not Opened");
    }
}
#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;
}
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    //I dont know what put here for display from sqlite
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What do you think the problem is? What have you already tried?

Comment: my problem is I dont know how store values from table sqlite in NSArray or NSDictionary (in storyboard)!!!

Comment: Have you read a SQLite tutorial? Have you read a UITableView tutorial? You shouldn't expect others to write code for you.

Comment: yes I do but I so confused!!! my friend please tell me about with code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a method which will fetch all players stored in sqlite say `findAllPlayers` . Create a dataSourceArray which will hold the players returned from the previous method. It would be easy to form model custom objects instead of dictionary for ease of use.

```
//Player.h

@interface Player : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger playerID;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *team;
```

A utility PlayerDatabase which inserts and fetches player instances from sqlite.

```
//PlayerDatabase.h

@class Player;
@interface PlayersDatabase : NSObject

+ (PlayersDatabase*)database;
- (NSArray *)findAllPlayers;
- (BOOL)insertPlayer:(Player *)player;

//PlayerDatabase.m
@implementation PlayersDatabase

static PlayersDatabase *_database;

+ (PlayersDatabase*)database {
    if (_database == nil) {
        _database = [[PlayersDatabase alloc] init];
    }
    return _database;
}

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSString *filePath = [self databasePath];
        if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
            NSString *sqLiteDb = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Players"
                                                                 ofType:@"db"];
            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:sqLiteDb
                                 toPath:filePath
                                  error:NULL];
        }

    }
    return self;
}

- (NSString *)databasePath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = paths[0];
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Players.db"];
}

- (NSArray *)findAllPlayers
{
    NSMutableArray *players = [NSMutableArray array];
    FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[self databasePath]];
    [database open];

    FMResultSet *resultSet = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * from Player ORDER BY Name"];

    while ([resultSet next]) {

        Player *player = [[Player alloc]init];

        player.playerID = [resultSet intForColumn:@"PlayerID"];
        player.name     = [resultSet stringForColumn:@"Name"];
        player.team     = [resultSet stringForColumn:@"Team"];

        [players addObject:player];

    }

    [database close];

    return players;
}

- (BOOL)insertPlayer:(Player *)player
{
     FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[self databasePath]];
     [db open];
     BOOL success =  [db executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO Player (Name,Team) VALUES (?,?);",player.name,player.team, nil];
     [db close];
     return success;
}
```

Now in the viewController with tableView, first populate the sqlite and then reload the tableView

```
//YourViewController.h 
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *names = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Ribery",@"Ronaldo",@"Messi",@"Zannati",@"Totti", nil];
    NSArray *teams = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"byern",@"R.Madrid",@"Barcelona",@"Inter",@"Rome", nil];
    for (int i = 0; i < [Name count]; i++)
    {
        Player *player = [[Player alloc]init];

        player.name = names[i];
        player.team = teams[i];

        [[PlayerDatabase database] insertPlayer:player];
    }

    self.players = [self findAllPlayers];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.players count];
}
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    //Here the dataSource array is of dictionary objects
    Player *player = self.players[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = player.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = player.team;

    return cell;
}
```

I have worked out a sample project following the above mentioned tutorial, the data was preloaded into the sqlite. So you might need to tweak it for your use.

[Source Code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35012982/Demo%20Projects/TestSQLite.zip)

Comment: my friend can you tell me what is findAllPlayers method??? I dont know about it

Comment: my friend tell me more about findAllPlayers , please with code

Comment: my friend I put this code in my app but not work!!! why??? can you test it??? this no error but don't display in tableview

Comment: @emma I haven't verified this, can you give me a little more time. I would give your a working demo code :)

Comment: Thank you my friend so I wait .please help me . thank you very much

Comment: @emma I have added source code to my answer. Please see if it's workig.

Comment: my friend thank you why libPods.a in framework folder is red??? why unknown compiler?

Comment: @emma I have used cocoapods to manage dependencies, open the project from *.xcworkspace instead of *.xcodeproj file

Comment: yes allright. my friend if I want when run app auto add nsarrays in sqlite must what I do??? I dont want add data with + button. I want auto add sqlite. please tell me about. thank you.

Comment: if I use cocoapods in my project not problem???

Comment: @emma In code I provided, there is a method to insert player from application. If you want to provide a static data set as it is with application. You can find the sqlite file in the resources of source code. Use any sqlite manager to insert data, I use a firefox addon SQLite Manager for preloading data. Yes you can use cocoapods, it would be easier to add dependent libraries. If you update the sqlite file, make sure to uninstall the application from simulator to see the newly added data.

Comment: my friend sorry for a lot of question. I so need sqlite and I am new in sqlite. if you dont angry can you tell me how create static data with your code. (I dont a lot syntax it) Im so sorry dear friend :-*

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29405/discussion-between-anupdas-and-emma)

Answer (score 0):

to get the data from the database sqlite....you need to write like these....and make some changes according to your code....

```
+(NSMutableArray*)getData
{
    NSString *strDestPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/DBEmployee.sqlite",NSHomeDirectory()];
    sqlite3 *db;
    NSMutableArray   *empArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    if(sqlite3_open([strDestPath UTF8String] , &db)  == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *query = @"SELECT * FROM Employee";
        char* err_msg;
        sqlite3_stmt* statement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [query UTF8String], -1,&statement, &err_msg) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                DatabaseKeys *emp = [[DatabaseKeys alloc]init];
                emp.Eno = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
                NSString *strn = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",emp.Eno];
                [empArr addObject:strn];


            }
        }
    }
    return empArr;
}
```

Comment: my friend "DatabaseKeys" & "emp.Eno" what is it???

Comment: my compiler unknown that.

Comment: my friend "DatabaseKeys" & "emp.Eno" what is it???

Comment: it is column name change there according to ur column name...